# Append Procedure to Event upon User Action

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

Say, I have a procedure which changes the random colour of a cell based on selection change. I know that I can code in a procedure for the worksheet `SelectionChange` event.

I guess Im asking, as in javascript where we can use `addEventListeners`, can we do something similar in Excel VBA.

[image]

What I am wondering is can this be done dynamically? I.e. when a user chooses an option, **then** I bind a procedure to the event `SelectionChange` of the worksheet.

Note, I know that I could declare a global boolean & use that to ascertain user action & use it in my `SelectionChange` event procedure.

Im just curious whether in Excel VBA, we can dynamically append procedures to events?

Comment: can you post the whole code?

Comment: Yes you can, you can `Call` or `Run` other procedures (most probably only the public) within your event procedure, so you can do tests in there and call different procedures regarding what the user have inputed!

Comment: @R3uK thanks, Im aware of that, Im curious as to whether we can use some sort of event listeners and then append the procedures to the events (like is Javascript etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't dynamically assign event handlers. Excel will always call the built-in event handlers (`SelectionChange`, `Calculate`, etc) and there's no way to substitute your own. You *can* create your own `Worksheet` variable using the `WithEvents` keyword, however, and choose *when* to start receiving the events. For example, start with this structure in one of your worksheets:

```
Dim WithEvents MySheet As Worksheet

Private Sub MySheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Debug.Print "Receiving events"

End Sub
```

As long as `MySheet` isn't bound to an active sheet, you're not going to receive any events. When you're ready to begin, call a custom subroutine to do the assignment:

```
Public Sub DoIt()

    Set MySheet = Sheet1

End Sub
```

Comment: Ah... fascinating. Thank you Bond.